# Show loading while reselect selector computation

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I use redux in my react application with long running computation in  selector, so I want to show loading indicator while it's working. Here is example code of selector:

```
const getItems = state => state.items;
const getFilters = state => state.filters;

export const getFilteredItems = createSelector([getItems, getFilters], 
(items, filters) => {
  //some long running filtering
  return filteredItems;
});
```

So question is what is most common way to show loading indicator in such case?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a flag that mutates through an action from componentDidMount, so the first time I don't display the content and instead just display a loading state. Then the selector would be something like:

```
const getItems = state => state.items;
const getFilters = state => state.filters;
const getPreLoading = state => state.preLoading;

export const getFilteredItems = createSelector([getPreLoading, getItems, getFilters], 
(preLoading, items, filters) => {
  if (preLoading) return null;

  //some long running filtering
  return filteredItems;
});
```